# Changing position of a row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]
In the above t-sql table I would like very much for the Total row to appear at the bottom. I have been wracking my head against this and in all of my other Queries simply using ORDER BY Status works as Total is alphabetically much farther down the list than most of our row values.

This is not the case here and I just can't figure out how to change it

I'm pretty new to sql and I'be been having a lot of difficulty even determining how to phrase a google search. So far I've just gotten results pertaining to Order By

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The results of a `select` query, unless an order is explicitly specified via an 'order by' clause, can be returned in *any* order. Moreover, the order in which they are returned is not even deterministic. Running the exact same query 3 times in succession might return the exact same result set in 3 different orderings.

So if you want a particular order to your table, you need to order it. An order by clause like

```
select *
from myTable t
where ...
order by case Status when 'Total' then 1 else 0 end ,
         Status
```

would do you. The 'Total' row will float to the bottom, the other rows will be ordered in collating sequence. You can also order things arbitrarily with this technique:

```
select *
from myTable t
where ...
order by case Status
           when 'Deceased'  then 1
           when 'Total'     then 2
           when 'Active'    then 3
           when 'Withdrawn' then 4
           else                  5
         end
```

will list the row(s) with a status of 'Deceased' first, followed by the row(s) with a status of 'Total', then 'Active' and 'Withdrawn', and finally anything that didn't match up to an item in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your Nicholas, in your example if I wanted to modify this and say make 'Total' always appear third would I be able to use a similar method? I.e: I don't understand the syntax of your case statement

Comment: @ThePhillipsEquation: see my amended answer. The order by clause can contain pretty much any expression you want to throw at it, including aggregate functions if your query has a `group by` clause. Neither the expression itself nor the columns involved need to be in the result set proper. The columns involved in the expression do have to be derivable -- e.g if you query uses `group by` the columns involved in the ordering expression will need to be either a grouping column or an aggregate function.

Comment: That was much clearer and it really explains a lot of the inconsistencies I've been noticing

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server (and most other databases), you can use `case` to sort certain [statūs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/status#Noun_3) above others:

```
order by
        case Status
        when 'Total' then 2
        else 1
        end
,       Status
```

In MS Access, you can use `iif`:

```
order by
        iif(Status = 'Total', 2, 1)
,       Status
```

Comment: statii ... Really? -- http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/877/what-is-the-plural-form-of-status

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Total' THEN 'zzz' ELSE STATUS END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional expressions in `order by`:

```
order by (case when status = 'Total' then 1 else 0 end),
         status
```